# How to notify in title text of page using react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am using sample program in React.JS.   I deployed the sample with chat program.

How to notify in title area(need to know some one is message me)?  Because i am working on other tab.

Kindly assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Sample Chat Program Link: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/

Comment: *Which* sample chat program? A link would be preferable.

Comment: You can dynamically change the document title of your page with `document.title`